# How to configure sentry scope in react?

Tags: reactjs, sentry

I am trying to configure scope and set a transaction name. how can I do it?
I am exporting my component with `profiler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sentry.configureScope((scope) =>
    scope.setTransactionName("your transcation name")
  );
```

try using this

Comment: can you show how youve used profiler

Comment: in your function component rather than exporting normally do it like                    
  export default Sentry.withProfiler(Capsule);